# How do you compose sbt projects into a single build?

Tags: sbt

A question about composing sbt projects:
I forked a library project (https://github.com/allenai/pipeline) and wish to hack on it vis-a-vis my project that uses it. If I put them in the same multi-project build ― really my preferred option over publishing locally and consuming ― sbt will not read the `project` dir of the nested fork (where `.scala` files and plugin definitions originally reside).
E.g. I try, in build.sbt:

```
lazy val pipeline = (project in file("pipeline"))

lazy val githubCruncher = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(pipeline)
```

And I get errors indicating directory `pipeline/project` is being ignored; the `build.sbt` itself of the nested project *is being read*, but sbt does not find what is defined alongside to it in its sibling `project` directory (and hence fails to load build definition).

So, must I squash the two projects into a single `build.sbt` or can I somehow elegantly compose the two without that? I am asking because this has also been a problem on other projects I work on where I ended up squashing each and every build definition minutia into one big monolith ― even though I'd prefer distributing some of the sub-projects as independent projects aside my own dev configuration.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience looks like everything inside the `project` directory of a project being pulled into a multi-project build ― needs to move to `project` under the *root* of the multi-project build, whereas the `build.sbt` of the pulled-in project does not have to be squashed ― a reference to it from from the top level `build.sbt` will work (unless that reference is followed by definitions for it right there in the top level `build.sbt`).

Sbt plugins coming from the pulled-in project then become applied to the unified multi-project build, and need to be disabled with `disablePlugins` for other sub-projects, if or where appropriate or desireable.

Comment: also maybe consider http://storm-enroute.com/mecha/ next time around, or the somewhat less scenario specific [local external projects workflow](http://code.technically.us/post/9545154150/local-external-projects-in-sbt)